# What is the meaning of -lNew in Makefile?

Tags: gnu-make

I am confused with the option **-lNew** in a Makefile.
What is the meaning of **-lNEW** ? 
Do you know where can I get more information?

```
TARGET = Example
OBJS = main.o user.o
CXXLIBS = -Wall -lNew -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
all: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET):$(OBJS)
        $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS) $(CXXLIBS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing GCC is your build toolchain, `-lNew` tells to the linker to add the library called "libNew.so" or "libNew.a" to the list of files to link in the output binary.